# Access And/Or exclusions

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have some sample data like:

```
|H.RISK|NOTE|NORMAL|
```

The `|` are actually in the data, it's a `String`.

I am using Access, and am trying to exclude records that contain `RISK` in the String.

Sample query:

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE (UCase(someTable.Field) NOT LIKE '*RISK*') AND (UCase(someTable.Field) NOT LIKE '*Blah*') AND someTable.SomeOtherField <> 4;
```

The problem is, the query is returning the above sample record, even though it does contain the string `RISK`.

I've tried the same query but switched to `OR` instead of `AND` but get the same results.

How can I properly structure this query to exclude records which contain certain strings?

Comment: It looks like you are using wildcards - that may be your problem.  See if this link helps:  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp

Comment: How are you running that query?  If from ADO/OleDb, or from within Access with the SQL Server compatible syntax option set, you need ANSI wild cards: `NOT LIKE '%RISK%'`

Comment: I'm using a scripting program called AutoIt to use ADODB to talk to access and execute queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing that it appears you are running using the SQL syntax, try with the correct wild card.

```
SELECT * FROM someTable WHERE (someTable.Field NOT LIKE '%RISK%') AND (someTable.Field NOT LIKE '%Blah%') AND someTable.SomeOtherField <> 4;
```

Comment: @HansUp because the `someTable.FIELD` may or may not be in upper case form, so to make sure we match, `UCase` is needed.

Comment: I edited, but it appears it may be necessary.  Either way, I think the wild card is the problem.

Comment: That was it. The wildcard. I'm used to Access' "fake sql" using `*` instead of the standard `%`. Thanks.