# MS Access Query using UCase function in WHERE clause does not return nulls

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to retrieve data from a MS Access table that does not include the word "survey" in a field named SurveyedBy. I developed the following query with a WHERE clause in order to limit results:

```
SELECT PropertyNumber, PropertyOwner, EnteredBy, EnterDate, SurveyedBy, SurveyDate, YearBuilt 
FROM MarshallSwift 
WHERE (LCase([SurveyedBy]) Not Like "*survey*");
```

However, when I run the query it does not return any records with null in that field. I tried using the UCase function instead with "*SURVEY*", but still do not get any records where the SurveyedBy field is null.

The closest I found to an answer was this: [Access And/Or exclusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20863744/access-and-or-exclusions). However, I am using DAO. I did try using the % for wildcard, but the results came up the same.

I am puzzled because the UCase function is supposed to return null according to this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/ucase-function-HA001228930.aspx. Perhaps I am not understanding the WHERE clause? Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: FIXED. I ran the query with the changes as suggested by both @Fionnuala and GordonLinoff. Both worked for me. I am voting GordonLinoff response as the answer because it cleared up some of my issues with Null. Thank you all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NULL` "fails" all tests except for `IS NULL`.  Check for it explicitly:

```
WHERE (LCase([SurveyedBy]) Not Like "*survey*") or SurveyedBy is null
```

Comment: So, even though the Not Like is included in the WHERE criteria, the Null will always fail that test unless I check for it with Is Null?

Comment: Just about any comparison with `NULL` returns "unknown".  "unknown" is treated as false for comparisons in SQL. There is nothing ambiguous about this.  `NULL` returns "unknown" for `like` and `not like`, just as it does for `=`, `<>`, `<`, `>`, and so on.

Comment: That actually makes sense. I ran the query along with Is Null and it worked just fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Null is not equal to anything, nor is it like anything, try:

```
WHERE (LCase([SurveyedBy] & "") Not Like "*survey*");
```

This will make SurveyedBy an empty string. You can also look at Nz ( http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php ) if you prefer.